# Connect to BitBucket via proxy

Tags: svn, proxy, mercurial, bitbucket

Hoi,

I try to *hg pull*
from my private repo on Bitbucket.org
into my local repo on my Windows machine
from behind the company proxy that requires Windows authentication.

- I found the proxy server and port (Internet options of IE)
- I found the settings `Mercurial.ini` file in my `%USERPROFILE%`
- I added this section to it ([info](http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hgrc.5.html#auth)):

  [http_proxy]
  host = `TheProxyServer` : `TheProxyServerPort`
  user = `MyWindowsLogin`
  passwd = `MyWindowsPassword`
- This works:

> C:\path\to\repo> hg pull
> http authorization required
> realm: Bitbucket.org HTTP
> user:

after I enter the credentials of Bitbucket, I get:

> searching for changes
> no changes found

**But** writing down the password in `Mercurial.ini` is obviously a *major* security issue (besides having to update this file each month because of our password policies).

Is it somehow possible to let Mercurial ask for the proxy credentials?
Or store these credentials in a more secure way?

**Edit:**

I tried with the same settings and SSH, but I got this:

> C:\path\to\repo> hg clone ssh://hg@bitbucket.org/*ME*/repo/
> running ""C:\Program Files\TortoiseHg\TortoisePlink.exe" -ssh -2 hg@bitbucket.org "hg -R *ME*/repo/ serve --stdio"
>
> abort: no suitable response from remote hg!

And a dialog : `"PuTTY Fatal Error - Network error: Connection timed out"`

**Edit2:**

This question came up because Subversion handles this situation correctly:

In the Subversion `servers` file I specify the proxy host and port too, and Subversion automagically sends my windows authentication to it. I don't have to enter nor write down my credentials anywhere when checking out source from the web via the proxy using e.g.

> C:\workingdir> svn checkout http://okarito.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ okarito-read-only
> ...
> Checked out revision 5.

Thanks in advance!
Jan

Comment: Can you use SSH without going through the proxy?

Comment: I hope my edit answered your question. I'm not 100% sure what you mean. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Another alternative is to run a local http proxy which then authenticates with your companies http proxy.  You can run [cntlm under Cygwin](http://www.theeggeadventure.com/wikimedia/index.php/Cntlm) and safely store an NTLMv2 hash in the cntlm conf file.  You then set you http proxy to be localhost:3128, and don't specify a username or password.

My other suggestion is to use TortoiseHg.  This will store your proxy information, but I'm not sure if it's stored securely.

Comment: Tortoise HG uses a password edit control in the properties dialog, nice!, but the password ends up in the same unencypted place: mercurial.ini

Comment: Installing a local proxy just for hg seems a bit overkill, but a good suggestion nonetheless. Thanks!

Comment: Using CNTLM you only need Mercurial to point to the proxy address:port - CNTLM stores the password etc.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `--config` option to `hg` as this allows you override configuration settings from the command line.  The syntax is `--config <section>.<name>=<value>`, so try this:

```
hg --config http_proxy.passwd=YourWindowsPassword pull
```

This will leave your password in your command history but this is probably better than in the `Mercurial.ini` file.