# How to avoid storing proxy password in TortoiseHG configuration file?

Tags: proxy, mercurial, tortoisehg

Currently I have a Mercurial.ini configuration which contains the following **http_proxy** section:

```
[http_proxy]
host = proxy.example.com
user = john_doe
passwd = super_secure_password
```

Is there any way for TortoiseHG or Mercurial to prompt the user for the proxy credentials and then store them in a secure file?  Something like the functionality of the mercurial keyring extension.  We would prefer that the password **super_secure_password** not be stored in a human-readable file that anyone can open.

Comment: Reading the keyring documentation, it interoperates nicely with TortoiseHG. Did you try?

Comment: The mercurial_keyring extension only works for storing repository-level permissions.  What I am looking for is a similar functionality for storing http_proxy variables.  I did not try writing a custom HG extension - looking to see if someone else has created one or ran across this problem.

Answer (score 1):

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/2061584/320456 which proposes installing the cntlm proxy locally as a workaround; [Does git clone work through NTLM proxies?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1783659/does-git-clone-work-through-ntlm-proxies#comment1671206_1783659) also mentions NTLM APS.